# Elasticsearch array of query strings

Tags: elasticsearch

I know this works:

```
{
"query": {

    "query_string": {
        "query": "reading,debating"
    }

}
```

It searchs for all occurances of the words reading or debating. I want to know if there is a way so that I instead of having a comma separated string we can insert an array of strings? To sort of look like this:

```
{
"query": {

    "query_string": {
        "query": ["reading","debating"]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your first example it is a QueryString query where elasticsearch internally handled the query understanding, and by default comma is a delimiter which is how your first query worked.

In this case probably what do you want is two or multiple term queries combined by a boolean(use "should" if you want OR logic and "must" if you want AND logic) query.

Here is how you can do it from curl:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

If you want to use it programmatically in Java, you can use the [QueryBuilders](http://www.codatlas.com/github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryBuilders.java?line=32) to construct a term queries and boolean query